# Как создать свой поток (output stream)?

Tags: c++

У меня есть класс Console, который формирует строку и выводит ее на экран (Имеется ввиду не DOS консоль, а своя собственная в окне приложения).
Чтобы вывести на нее информацию, приходится писать так:

```
std::ostringstream os;
os << "value X = " << x;
console.print(os.str());
```

Каждый раз так писать очень неудобно, хочется использовать класс так же, как и при работе со стандартными потоками ввода/вывода, примерно так:

```
console << "value X = " << x;
//или через функцию метод
conslole.get() << "value X = " x;
```

Есть способ реализовать такое? Желательно без сторонних библиотек

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13703823/276994

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Если вы хотите, чтобы ваш класс *выглядел* как `ostream`, то всё, что вам нужно сделать - перегрузить оператор `<<`:

```
class Console {
private:
    std::ostringstream os;

public:
    template <class T>
    Console &operator<<(const T &x) {
        os << ':' << x << ':';
        return *this;
    }

    std::string to_string() const { return os.str(); }
};
```

[*Источник*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/823014/4863012)

Теперь вы можете использовать вашу консоль как поток вывода:

```
Console con;
con << "abc" << 123;
```

Если же вам нужно, чтобы ваш класс *являлся* потоком вывода, придётся наследоваться от базовых классов потоков вывода и переопределять их методы.